# Inconsistency in Swift optional protocol behaviour

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Coming from .Net, I am trying to learn Swift3/iOS and got puzzled by the following apparent inconsistent behaviour of optional protocol members. I suspect its something got to do with the juggling between objc/swift words, but what am I missing here actually?

```
// In playground, given below:

@objc protocol SomePtotocol {
    @objc optional func someMethod()
}

class SomeDelegate: NSObject, SomePtotocol {
}

class SomeController: NSObject {
    var delegate: SomePtotocol = SomeDelegate()
}

// This works and compiles without error

let controller = SomeController()
controller.delegate.someMethod?()      // No error, typed as '(() -> ())?'

// But this fails to even compile ??

let delegate = SomeDelegate()
delegate.someMethod?()  // Error: 'SomeDelegate' has no member 'someMethod'
```

I would expect either both to fail or both pass, so if someone could please enlighten me on this anomaly.

Comment: If you're learning iOS and Swift then my recommendation would be to **not** use `@objc` and `NSObject`. And prefer `struct` to `class` unless you try to do something a struct cannot do. Likewise, prefer `let` over `var`. This code is not Swifty at all.

Comment: I do know swift's preference to struct over class but unfortunately that also another area of concept that I am struggling to wrap my head around as in .Net, I was taught to prefer class over struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two blocks of code is the type of the variable involved.

In the first block, `delegate` is explicitly typed as `SomePtotocol`, and  this protocol defines the `someMethod` method, so your statement is valid.

In the second block, `delegate` is implicitly typed as `SomeDelegate` and although this class conforms to `SomePtotocol`, it doesn't implement the optional method `someMethod`, so you get an error.

If you change your second block to

```
let delegate: SomePtotocol = SomeDelegate()
delegate.someMethod?()
```

which is equivalent to the first block, then there is no error.